# C++ coverity issue STRING_OVERFLOW

Tags: c++, c, coverity

I see a coverity issue for the following code:

```
#define LEN 32
typedef char BUFFER[LEN+1];

void func(char* str)
{
    BUFFER buf;
    strcpy((char*)buf, str);
}
```

The issue says -
"Copy into fixed size buffer (STRING_OVERFLOW)" for the strcpy() line.

I see that since str is char* its length cannot be predicted (although as per my code it will always be 32). So I tried to use strncpy() and set the null terminating character. Something like this:

```
strncpy((char*)buf, str, LEN);
buf[LEN] = '\0';
```

But this does not resolve the issue. Am I understanding the error right? Or is there something extra to be done?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Problem with `strncpy()`: If there is no null character among the first n character of `str`, the string placed in `buf` will not be null-terminated. So `strncpy()` does not guarantee that the destination string will be null-terminated. Use `snprintf`

Comment: @DavidRanieri The next line after the strncpy ensures null termination

Comment: @M.M I know, but this can be the cause of the coverity issue/warning

Comment: @OP after changing to strncpy is the error message exactly the same, or is it a different error message?   BTW prefer to use `sizeof buf - 1` instead of `LEN`.

Comment: If the `strncpy()` call triggers the *same* coverity issue, I'd say that's a bug in Coverity.  I would expect it to trigger a different issue about `strncpy()` not ensuring nul termination of `buf` if `str` is too long (e.g. if `strlen(str) > LEN`).    In rough terms, Coverity will analyse the `strcpy()` and `strncpy()` calls in isolation (i.e.  in the latter case, `buf[LEN] = '\0'` will not stop a squawk on the `strncpy()` call).

Comment: @M.M The error after strncpy() is exactly the same.

Comment: @Peter As for the contents of str, it is confirmed that it is always == 32 chars, never > 32. But I get your point that since the Fixed size buffer issue is solved by strncpy(), there must be some other error triggered.

Comment: @HrishikeshBawane  Your (calling) code may provide those conditions as guarantees.   But coverity is probably analysing code statements in isolation, rather than in context of your program as a whole.    Some static analysers do the latter (if they have visibility of the complete code of a program) but, IIRC, coverity is not one of them  (such a thing is practically more difficult to achieve in C or C++, compared with other programming languages).

Comment: The problem is not that the code is correct or not, coverity warns about the use of an unsafe function "per-se" even if you make sure the string is null-terminated one line below.

Answer (score 0):

> strcpy((char*)buf, str);

The cast to char * is unneeded.

Try
strcpy(buf, str);